# /usr/bin/sqlite3: argument list too long

Tags: bash, sqlite

I'm trying to insert the contents of a file into an sqlite database, which is about 350k characters long.

```
VALUE=$(cat file)
sqlite3 database.db "UPDATE table SET value='$VALUE';"
```

But, I get an "Argument list too long error"

I tried looking it up, but most of the solutions are for find, ls, etc.
How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

The sqlite3 shell has a [readfile()](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html#file_i_o_functions) function that returns a blob with the contents of the given file.

```
$ sqlite3 foo.db
sqlite> CREATE TABLE example(file TEXT, contents BLOB);
sqlite> INSERT INTO example VALUES('foo.txt', readfile('foo.txt'));
```

or whatever

Answer (score 0):

You are on an operating system which has upper limits on how long the command line can be, measured in bytes. (Most OSes have such a limit.) The last argument to `sqlite3`, because it contains the contents of the file, measures over 350k bytes.

Instead, you should use a `COPY` command to have `sqlite3` read directly from the file. Something like

```
sqlite3 database.db "COPY table FROM file"
```

You will probably need to edit the data file slightly to provide the data in a format `COPY` expects.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I can't find any information about the COPY method for sqlite3.

Comment: Hm, I saw a reference to a `COPY` command on one website, but having trouble finding it in any official sqlite documentation.

Comment: Oh, apparently it was removed. `.import` may be what you want.

Comment: I don't think .import can help. I think you've got it confused. .import seems to be for importing a csv to a db. But, I want to set a field to the contents of a text file.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with sqlite to offer a fully realized solution. The best way forward is probably doing to be to create a slightly different *new* file, based on the contents of the original one, first, then use `.import` to pull that into a temporary table, and use `UPDATE` to read from the temporary table. (And yes, I should delete this answer and make this a comment to your question.)

Answer (score 0):

This one-line code should work:

```
sqlite3 database.db "UPDATE table SET value=readfile('file');"
```